# Can I publish a feed of my EventBrite meetings to appear on my Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, events

I am attending a lot of EventBrite meetings and want an automated way to put it on my Google Calendar.

Comment: I think someone will have to write a script for it. Using Google calendar API, it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

If EventBrite provides some kind of RSS feed, you can send this feed to [RSS2iCal](http://arnout.engelen.eu/scripts/rss2ical.php), which will create an iCal file, that you'll then be able to integrate [as an external calendar](http://www.googletutor.com/quick-google-calendar-tip-add-by-url/) into Google Calendars

Comment: Sadly not available anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Just started using [Plancast](http://plancast.com/) to do just that — import my events from Eventbrite and several other services and export them as a feed suitable for Google Calendar.

Comment: Plancast has, apparently, stopped updating their services around 2013.